# Vim cursor goes line down when esc mapped to jk

Tags: vim

I have

```
imap jk <C-[>
```

in my vimrc, but when I use it on the end of line (when cursor is on $ when list is on) cursor goes to beginning of next line. How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works normally for me.

I assume interfering mappings or settings.

First you should try

```
:inoremap jk <C-[>
```

can you provide more details

- version
- verbose set <sup>1</sup>
- map j
- map k
- map jk

I have a hunch it might be the `virtualedit` settings or stuff like that interfering

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> get it with</sub>

```
:redir >> ~/file.log
:verbose set
:redir END
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and figured out that the described effect appears when you accidentally map

```
:inoremap jk <Esc> "comment => maped to '<Esc> '
```

Which would be <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>

Or if you have a trailing whitespace in this line. This can be observed by setting

```
:set list
```

Comment: Thank you. I had a trailing space which caused it to jump to the start of next line if I press jk at the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sometimes, SO still better than LLM :)

Answer (score 0):

First hack is:

```
imap jk <Left><C-[>
```

But maybe there is better solution?